# Windows Mobile 6.1 taking ages to deploy - is it me?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile, handheld

I have taken over a colleague's project and am working on a Windows Mobile 6.1 project and deploying it to a Windows Handheld Pocket PC (barcode scanner).

I have however noticed that when I do "Deploy to device" it takes at least 5-10 minutes to deploy the code and this is a big productivity killer.

I have looked online and the only thing that is supposed to make a difference is unticking a box that says something like "Check for latest version..." I unticked it but it made no difference whatsoever.

Please note I am using a real device not an emulator

Is there anything I can do to speed things up? I have been working in .NET previously and running the program happens almost instantly and all of a sudden I have to wait 10 minutes to test the program - and if something doesn't work I have to fix and wait again.

Basically it is very frustrating.

Any advice on the matter will be greatly appreciated

Comment: anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your device's connections "USB to PC" (on device) setting. There is an option called "Enable advanced network functionality". That should be checked for faster transfers.

If you have wireless network you can run cable-free debug and deploy http://www.turboirc.com/ppc/s5.htm (automates this). That will also work with an ethernet connection (if the device supports it).

Comment: Wireless debugging has definitely intrigued me. Does that mean I dont have to dock it every time I want to test something? If this is the case then I will definitely look into this on monday. Thanks for your reply @josef

Comment: Right, if you use the linked setup or do it manually (starting remote debug tools on device) you do not need to dock the device.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your project is set to deploy the Setup file to the application.

Go into Configuration Manager

[image: How to find CM]

Make sure that you are not deploying the setup file whenever you start debugging your application.

The setup file would create installers for all the controls you are using, any service packs, .NET Compact Framework updates, etc. that your project may call for. If it is already on the device, you do not need to do this every time.

[image: Configuration Manager]

Comment: thank you for your reply. I will try it when I get back to work and let you know if it worked. Thanks for taking your time to reply